# How to use keydown event in textarea?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am not very used to using javascript but I have gotten sick of manually repeating a tast at work. When I write in a discussion forum I need a quick short command, like Ctrl-Alt-z, to insert some text into a textarea object.

I have already written a function that inserts the text at the text cursor insertAtCursor(text). The ID of the textarea is "content".

I know how to solve the problem of checking for key combinations. The problem I have is basically to check for any keyboard input at all.

I have tried the following:

```
document.keydown(function(event){
  alert("Test");
});
```

However, it does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: attach a keydown event to the actual textarea. You're attaching it to the whole page.

Comment: Both answers below are good, so no need for an almost identical third one, just your code can be modified for example also to `document.onkeydown = function(event){alert("Test" + event.target);};` to be functional. But undoubtedly better to attach an event handler directly to textarea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're going to have a tough time if you're looking for cross-browser solutions. Here's something to help you: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Basically, you'd want something like this:

```
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('keydown', function (e){
    // Do your key combination detection
}, false);
```

[MDN on events. Probably more helpful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It solved my problem. So did Lions answer but since you was quicker I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

textarea.onkeydown = function ()
{
   alert("Test");
};
```

Using jQuery ([delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)).

```
$("body").delegate("textarea", "keydown",function(e){
        alert("Test");
        //code logic goes here
        //if(e.which == 13){
        //Enter key down    
    }
});
```

Or

```
$('textarea').live("keydown", function(e) {
    alert("Test");
    // e.which is which key, e.g. 13 == enter
});
```

Docs on [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
Docs on [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: live() is deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9, people should use [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) rather. (I know this is an old answer, I up-voted).

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('textarea') // find a DOM element (by tag name at this case)
  .addEventListener('keydown', // bind an event listener for "keydown" event
    e => { // declare a callback function when that event happens
      console.log(e.target.value) // print the target node value (<Textarea>)
    })
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```