# How to call JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how to rewrite this code. 
I have simple code which contains JS code in html code (`onkeydown` event).

I want put JS code to extern JS file and only call method. But i don't know how. Can you tell me how?

Code is:

```
<textarea onkeydown="if(event.keyCode===9){var v=this.value,s=this.selectionStart,e=this.selectionEnd;this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e);this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;return false;}">
</textarea>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
// in a new js-file
function onKeyDown(event) {
      if(event.keyCode===9){var v=this.value,s=this.selectionStart,e=this.selectionEnd;this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e);this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;
      return false;}
}

var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown.bind(textarea));
</script>

<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i test your code, but it not working. What doesn't mean `event` in `onKeyDown(event)`?

Comment: Just a side not that this will not work on IE8 due to addEventListener, consider adding a check for attachEvent, or add a polyfill or use jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a file myscripts.js with

```
<script>
    function myFunc(event) {
        if(event.keyCode===9){
            var v=this.value,s=this.selectionStart,e=this.selectionEnd;
            this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e);
            this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;
            return false;
        }
    }
<script>
```

And a html file with

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
<textarea onkeydown="myFunc(event)"></textarea>
```

Also take a look at this link [How to use keydown event in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511250/how-to-use-keydown-event-in-textarea)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hum externalise your JS code.

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<script>
document.getElementById("mytext").onkeydown = function(event){
   if(event.keyCode===9){
var v=this.value, s=this.selectionStart, e=this.selectionEnd; this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e); this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1; 
return false;
}
//You're function here
}
</script>
```

Comment: You've used the wrong "your" in both cases on this answer, just a heads up. Might want to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <textarea id="mytest"></textarea>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("mytest").onkeydown = function (event){
            alert("keydown");
            if(event.keyCode===9){
                var v=this.value,
                    s=this.selectionStart,
                    e=this.selectionEnd;
                    this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substrin(e);
                this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;      
                return false;
        }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pk2jLa0j/1/)